# $E(X \mid Y) = Y$ and $E(Y \mid X) = X$ implies $X = Y$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory

I'm asked to show that if $X, Y$ are random variables (discrete or continuous) and $E(X|Y) = Y$, $E(Y|X) = X$, then $X = Y$ almost surely.

I'd like to argue as follows:  Suppose not.  Then

$$\{X\neq Y\} = \bigcup _{r\in\mathbb{Q}} \left(\{X<r\} \cap \{r<Y\}\right) \cup \bigcup _{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\left(\{X>r\} \cap \{r>Y\}\right)$$

has positive measure, and hence without loss of generality there's some $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\{X<r<Y\}$ has positive measure.  Let's call this set $C$.  Then we get:

$$\int_CX<\mu(C)\cdot r<\int_CY=\int_CE(Y|X)=\int_CX$$

where the second-last equality comes from the definition of conditional expectation, and the last equality comes from one of the given equations.  But the above is a contradiction, so that does it.

The problem here is that I've only used one of the given assumptions, so have I implicitly used the other one somewhere?  Is there some measurability-related concern I'm overlooking?

Comment: Here's the flaw: the equation $\int_C Y=\int_C E(Y|X)$ is only valid for sets $C\in \sigma(X)$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34101/conditional-expectation-eab-b-and-eba-a-implies-a-b

Comment: Alright, so for $C\in\sigma(X)$, $\int_CY = \int_CE(Y|X) = \int_CX$ (since $E(Y|X) = X$).  Similarly, for $C\in\sigma(Y)$ using the other given.  So $\int_C(Y-X)=0$ for all $C\in\sigma(X)\cup\sigma(Y)$.  Does this get me anywhere?

Comment: I don't think so. Please look at the argument in the MSE question that I linked to above.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't familiar with the definition Didier was using for conditional expectation, but I get it now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $E[X|Y]=Y$ almost surely and $E[Y|X]=X$ almost surely then $X=Y$ almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666843/if-exy-y-almost-surely-and-eyx-x-almost-surely-then-x-y-almost-surel)

Answer (score 2):

One can use the [law of total variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance):
$$
\operatorname{var}(X) = \mathbb{E}(\operatorname{var}(X \mid Y)) + \operatorname{var}(\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y)) = \mathbb{E}(\operatorname{var}(X \mid Y)) + \operatorname{var}(Y)
$$
so 
$$
\operatorname{var}(X) \le \operatorname{var}(Y),
$$
and by the *same* argument, but with $X$ and $Y$ interchanged, the reverse inequality also holds.  It follows that
$$
\mathbb{E}(\operatorname{var}(X \mid Y)) = 0 \text{ and }\mathbb{E}(\operatorname{var}(Y \mid X)) = 0.
$$
If the conditional expected value of something is $Y$ and the conditional variance is $0$, then that "something" is "almost surely" equal to $Y$.

Comment: You're assuming sq integrability?