# Is it true that if $E(X\mid Y)=Y$ and $E(Y\mid X)=X$, then $X$ equals $Y$?

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$, $Y$ are random variables and $E(X|Y)=Y, E(Y|X)=X$. Is this sufficient to show that $X=Y$? Or at least $X = Y$ almost surely?

Comment: Maybe I'm just not used to the notation, but what does $E(X|Y) = Y$ mean?  Expectation inputs a distribution over a domain and outputs a single value from that domain.  How can a distribution equal a domain value?

Comment: @DanielV Conditional expectation conditioned on a random variable is a random variable. For instance the say we have $X$ and $Y$ two N(0,1)'s with correlation $\rho$. Then the expectation of $X$ conditional on $Y$ is going to depend on what $Y$ is: $E(X|Y) = \rho Y$ in this case. Y is a random variable.

Comment: Ah, I guess ${\rm E}(X | Y) = \lambda y. {\rm E}(X | Y = y)$.

Comment: Yes, this is sufficient for $X=Y$ almost surely.  This has been asked before but I cannot find the link right now.  The easiest proof is if you assume $X$ and $Y$ have finite second moments and then compute $E[(X-Y)^2]$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103472/ex-mid-y-y-and-ey-mid-x-x-implies-x-y-almost-surely, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34101/conditional-expectation-ea-mid-b-b-and-eb-mid-a-a-implies-a-b?noredirect=1&lq=1.